# Optimize deletion of XML elements without children

Tags: xml, t-sql, xpath, sql-server-2012, xquery

I have a large `XML` value stored in variable. I am first deleting all `condition` elements with attribute `@Suspended` set to `1`:

```
 SET @A.modify('delete /definitions/definition/conditions/group/condition[@Suspended=1]')
```

Then I want to delete all `group` elements which have not got any `condition` elements left (no children elements are left after the previous deletion). I have manage to do this using the following statement:

```
SET @A.modify('delete for $Node in /definitions/definition/conditions/group 
                                where not ( ($Node/condition)[1] instance of element() )
                                return $Node
                             ')
```

The first deletion is pretty fast - `0` seconds. The second deletion execution time is about `8` seconds.

I am looking for a better/faster way to perform the second deletion if possible.

---

The following is sample `XML` structure:

```
<definitions>
  <definition>
    <conditions>
      <group name="Group 1">
        <condition name="condition" type="answerisin" objType="question" objID="213219" Suspended="1">
          <value name="parameter">12</value>
        </condition>
        <condition name="condition" type="answerisin" objType="question" objID="113219" Suspended="1">
            <value name="parameter">4</value>
        </condition>
      </group>
    </conditions>
  </definition>
  <definition>
    <conditions>
      <group name="Group 1">
        <condition name="condition" type="answerisin" objType="question" objID="213219" Suspended="1">
          <value name="parameter">34</value>
        </condition>
      </group>
      <group name="Group 2">
        <condition name="condition" type="answerisin" objType="question" objID="213219">
          <value name="parameter">12</value>
        </condition>
      </group>
    </conditions>
  </definition>
</definitions>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using this rather complex statement. What about `delete /definitions/definition/conditions/group[empty(condition)]`? I'm not sure if it is faster, though: depends on whether SQL Server optimized your query badly or changing the actual data takes a lot of time.

Comment: I guess this is answered best with a [reference to some reference](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/fn_empty.html). In this case, it checks whether the result sequence of the child axis step `condition` is empty, in other words a test for missing `condition` children. In some sense it's a kind of negation `[condition]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rewrite to this:

```sql
set @A.modify('delete /definitions/definition/conditions/group[empty(condition)]');
```

But I doubt it will be any faster. The query plan is somewhat different but much the same in the parts that matter for performance.

Another option that might work for you is to shred the XML to a table variable on `definitions/definition`, modify the XML in the table variable and then recreate the XML using `for xml path`.

```
declare @T table(X xml);

insert into @T(X)
select T.X.query('.')
from @A.nodes('/definitions/definition') as T(X);

update @T
set X.modify('delete /definition/conditions/group[empty(condition)]');

set @A = (
         select T.X as '*'
         from @T as T
         for xml path(''), root('definitions')
         );
```

Shredding the XML and modifying in small chunks was in my tests 10x faster than modifying a big XML. But that depends of course on what your actual XML looks like and if shredding on `definitions/definition` is fine grained enough.